# Login with "AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()"

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Android Studio to create an Android application that allows me to connect to Firebase, specifically to authentication, to do the login with email and password using `AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()`.
So, I am using the following code:

```
startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false, true)
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo_auth)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
```

But the result does not meet my expectations for the following reason: The activity that is displayed does not ask me for the email address and password to do the login, but I find myself faced with creating a new account as indicated below:

[image: Premiere Vue]

[image: Deuxieme Vue]

How to use `AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()` to login by introducing email and password and having a clear response.
Thank you everyone.
Thank you in advance.